# undefined method beginning_of_day for string with ransacker custom filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ransack

I'm getting below mentioned error. any idea how i can fix it ?

```
undefined method `beginning_of_day' for "2018-01-01":String
/lib/ransack_ext.rb
config.add_predicate old, arel_predicate: current
end
config.add_predicate 'gteq_datetime',
arel_predicate: 'gteq',
formatter: ->(v) { v.beginning_of_day }
```

**Code:**

**Projects.rb (ActiveAdmin)**

```
filter :project_event_date, label: 'By Project Event Date', as: :date_range
```

**Project.rb(model)**

```
 has_many :project_events, dependent: :destroy

 ransacker :project_event_date do
  "project_events.event_date"
 end
```

Comment: Yeah, stop calling `beginning_of_day` on `String`. It isn't gonna work.

Comment: what is your `event_date` column type? change it to date

Comment: @seethrough its date type

Comment: put `'date(project_events.event_date)'` instead of `"project_events.event_date"`

Comment: @seethrough it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Casting the field from datetime to date in the datasource solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations/beginning_of_day), `beginning_of_day()`:

> Converts Date to a Time (or DateTime if necessary) with the time portion set to the beginning of the day (0:00)

A `String` is not a `Date`. So, convert your `String` to a `Date` and you should be good to go.

Comment: how i can do it ?

Comment: Perhaps you will find [this resource](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+convert+string+to+date) helpful. In particular the first item.

Comment: @jvillian smart comment, haha

Comment: @jvillian to_date can convert it into date. but where i should call this to_date function ?

Comment: in ?
 
   `ransacker :project_event_date do
     "project_events.event_date"
  end`

Comment: Is the error occurring here: `formatter: ->(v) { v.beginning_of_day }`? If so, perhaps `formatter: ->(v) { v.to_date.beginning_of_day }`. Or, wherever the error is being raised.

Comment: yes but that is present in 
`/lib/ransack_ext.rb file`

Comment: @jvillian do i need to override something in my 

'ransacker :project_event_date do "project_events.event_date" end' 

block ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to date first, then apply beginning_of_day method like this:-

```
Date.parse("2018-01-01").beginning_of_day
```

Comment: where he should apply this at?

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

`ruby
ransacker :project_event_date, type: :date do
  Arel.sql("project_events.event_date")
end`

ransacker block result should be built using `Arel` like it shown on [Using Ransacker Guide](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers)

active_admin has custom formatter for predicate like
`formatter: proc { |v| v.beginning_of_day }`
so you need to convert passed value into date

best way will be to provide `type` or `formatter` to ransacker